# Using spectacle to generate swagger documentation

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger, spectacle

I installed spectacle globally with :

```
npm install -g spectacle-docs
```

now when I try to use it I get

```
spectacle is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Why is that ?

Comment: `npm list -g`  and check if the directories are in the `$PATH`.

Comment: The list i too long I don't see everything >.<

Comment: You don't need to see everything, just the part related to spectacles. Even if you are on windows, there must be some kind of output redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Check `%appdata%/Roaming/npm` folder and look for `spectacle.cmd` file. If it is there, then add this path to the `Path` variable in System Variables